# Windows 8 setup DLL errors

Tags: windows-xp, setup, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have an Windows XP 32 bit machine that I want to upgrade to windows 8.1 (since RIP windows XP) and when I mount the ISO into the machine I get this error:

CxxFrameHandler3 could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll
and Autorun could not be run or is corrupt. Error 0xF

I don't know what is happening.

Halp pls

Comment: How exactly are you mounting the ISO?  What software are you using?  Since there is no direct upgrade to Windows 8 from Windows XP, you are better off booting to the installation disk, and formatting and installing Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things about what you're trying to do don't make sense:

- XP has no facility for mounting ISOs (so you must be using a third-party one, which you have not mentioned in the question)
- XP is not a supported upgrade path for 8.1

Supported upgrade paths: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/jj203353.aspx

To go from XP or Vista to 8.1, you must either do a fresh install by booting off the disc directly, or upgrade through an older OS (7 or 8) first.